# Model returns null when passing the grid with calculation value in controller to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here i have two filed on is allocation and other filed is amount. I want show third filed in ((Allocation/100)*Amount) n show in the  third filed.

I have code For this but it is not worked.in View my Model return Null Value.here below i show the code of my Controller.

```
public ActionResult recommendedportfolio()
  {
     using (var db = new WFTradeEntities1())
     {
        return View(db.Schema_Details.ToList());
      }
  }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult recommendedportfolio(int sName)
 {
    using (var db = new WFTradeEntities1())
     {
      var tr = db.Schema_Details.ToList().Where(C => C.RID == sName).Sum((x =>        x.Allocation / 100));
      var total = db.Schema_Details.Sum((x => x.Lum_Sum_Amount * tr )&& (x =>x.SIPAmount * tr ));
      return PartialView("_PortfolioTable", total);
      }
}
```

so Please help me out i want two display that amount in third raw n in forth raw same as counting..
in this below image i can display my query with output.i have to fix lum_Sum_Amount 25000.
In Allocation some % are given 50% 20% 30% = total 100%.
what i do in view lum_Sum_Amount calculate with Allocation percentage value n getting some value that value display in total.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weF76.png)

Comment: add some tag to your question related to technology

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I m uisng asp.net MVC(model-view-controller)

Comment: Please edit your question with clear issue.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel now is it ok?

Comment: Done.looks good

Comment: Are you getting null value for sName or in view or partial view?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers i have change my query like this var x = db.Schema_Details.GroupBy(C => C.RID == sName)
.SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(row => new
    {
         row.Allocation,
          row.Lum_Sum_Amount,
          Percent = (row.Allocation/100) / grp.Sum(dd =>       dd.Lum_Sum_Amount)
                      })
            );

Comment: But you are getting null value in partial view right? and update your code in original question

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers yes i add show the my new write query but in this also X in calculation is coming 0

Comment: so your original issue is regarding linq query rather than Partial view

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers yes i don't knew how to write query in the controller n calculate my percentage.                                   ((Allocation/100) * Lum_Sum_Amount) in this i have to first checked the value sName ==RID then listed item on calculate the amount

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers if you knw how to write query then please knew me how to write

Comment: @vidhipatel - Can you paste some sample data and desirable output here?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers i have change n update the post plez check n i have also add one image.in this image my table structure n also with query n lats filed total in i have manual amount add show you can understand which value i want display i want get total amount can you help me out ?

Comment: @vidhipatel- I will try to come up with solution ASAP

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers i m wating for this bcz i have complete my task till today 2 p.m

Comment: @vidhipatel - In Image you have shown sql query. which is correct? and you want to replicate this in LINQ?

Comment: yes i want to do in controller my @UbiquitousDevelopers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All you need to create a model

```
public class LINQDATA2
{
    public Int64 SID { get; set; }
    public Int64 RID { get; set; }
    public string Schema_Name { get; set; }
    public string SType { get; set; }
    public string InvestmentType { get; set; }
    public int Allocation { get; set; }
    public int Lum_Sum_Amount { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
}
```

Because dynamic column is not possible in LINQ.

Now perform query like

```
var x = data.Select(i => new LINQDATA2 { SID = i.SID, Total = (i.Allocation / 100) * i.Lum_Sum_Amount }).ToList();
```

and pass this model to partial view

Comment: its do can i ask one thing int allocation n int lum_sum_Amount i have if passed money then in controller can i conveted???if yes then how?

Comment: change type as per your need

Comment: Devlopers but in mapping time in my project given error

Comment: you passed SID but i have to passed sName which comes from view side to controller so its given error not excepting sName variable

Comment: i want write this query in controller how can i write this sql query i want to passed in cantroller.                                   
 SELECT     SID, RID, Schema_Name, SType, InvestmentType, Allocation, Lum_Sum_Amount, 
 CAST(Allocation AS NUMERIC(12,2))/100.0 * Lum_Sum_Amount   as total
 FROM         Schema_Details where RID = 1

Comment: Can you see my code in comment above @Ubiquitous Developers

Comment: you want total with two decimal point right? that's the query right?

Comment: rather changing in controller, change it to view like this
@{
     var format = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.Allocation);
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Allocation, format)